# Nginx serving off the wrong root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, debian, php-fpm

I have 2 `sites-enabled`, with `server_name` as follows:

```
server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com
```

and

```
server_name dev.mysite.com
```

**Problem:** When I access the website via its IP address, by looking at the access/error logs, it appears that nginx is serving off the `root` of `dev.mysite.com`.

How does nginx decide which to serve? Can we force it to serve off the `root` of `www.mysite.com` when the site is visited using its ip address?

**conf**

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    root /var/www/mysite/public;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Briefly:** you haven't told Nginx which `server {...}` to choose from - so it chose the first one.

Nginx passes requests to the default server. To do this, it matches the `Host` header against the `server_name`. If an IP address is used, the `Host` header will contain the IP address (which means it can be used to match against the `server_name`).

In the case where no `server_name` matches the Host header, nginx will choose the server in the following way:

1. The server explicitly set as default.

   - This is done (in the case of port 80) with `listen 80 default_server`
2. If there is no default_server, the first server listed in the configuration is used.

   - It is important to note that, when using wildcards, the order of file inclusion in nginx is indeterminate

To quote from the [Nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen):

> If the directive has the `default_server` parameter, then the enclosing
>   `server {...}` block will be the default server for the `address:port`
>   pair. This is useful for name-based virtual hosting where you wish to
>   specify the default server block for hostnames that do not match any
>   server_name directives. If there are no directives with the
>   default_server parameter, then the default server will be the first
>   server block in which the `address:port` pair appears. The
>   `default_server` parameter appeared in version 0.8.21 thus deprecating
>   the parameter default.

Recommended reading:

- [Nginx Documentation: Server Names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)
- [Nginx Documentation: How Nginx Processes a Request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Answer (score 1):

root can also be defined under http scope before server. You can set your default root there.

```
html {
    root /default/root

    server {
        root /site/root
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My case was not an IP address issue, but this post is the first that shows up when searching nginx serving the wrong root. My nginx was configured with 3 different domain names with 3 different server blocks each with a different root. 1 of the domain names was serving from the wrong root.

In my case I discovered that one of my server blocks contained these 2 lines:

```
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
```

While I had 2 other server blocks that contained only:

```
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
```

Each server block had a different server_name and different root, but 2 of them ended up showing web pages from the same root.

It all worked correctly after removing the following line from the first case:

```
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
```

I assume this line showed up because of a copy paste error on my part. But I don't really recall where it came from.